# Laravel Current User off of a Fetch Request

Tags: laravel, typescript, fetch

so I am trying to get the active user off of a fetch request to my backend.

My front end code is:

```
let apiToken: string | null = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');



        fetch('http://192.168.0.6:8000/api/testURL', {
            method: "POST",
            //@ts-ignore
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json, text-plain, */*',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': apiToken
            },
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(function(response): void {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function(err): void {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

I have a CSRF token in a meta tag that is generated from csrf_token();

My backend code is:

```
    Route::post('/testURL', function(Request $request)
{

    $status = $request->input('status');
    $comment = $request->input('comment');
    $prospectType = $request->input('prospectType');
    $leadId = $request->input('leadId');
    $requestUser = $request->user();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => $status,
        'comment' => $comment,
        'prospectType' => $prospectType,
        'leadId' => $leadId,
        'user' => $requestUser
    ]);
    });
```

The end result from the API call back shows 'user' as null.

I have tried Auth::user() & Auth::id() and they all return null.

I am at a lose and tried using Sanctum to create a validation token which when I added an auth:sanctum middleware it returned a 302 to redirect.

(The same redirect is happening when I apply a vanilla "auth" to a non-Sanctum token'd request).

**The request out of all of this!**
I want to ensure I have user by ID validation when I send up the request from the frontend to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the reason the request was not working correctly was the sanctum.php config file did not have my local IP (what I am running my php artisan serve off of) in its 'stateful' array.

I hope this helps anyone! That was five hours of my life.